# External table in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

`EMPDET` is an external table containing the columns `EMPNO` and `ENAME`. What is external table in oracle database?
Why can/cannot we update/delete from an external table?

```
A. UPDATE empdet
SET ename = 'Amit'
WHERE empno = 1234;

B. DELETE FROM empdet
WHERE ename LIKE 'J%';
```

Comment: If this is literally from the test then it's unethical to post the question here.

Answer (score 5):

An external table in an oracle-database is a way of accessing data residing in some `.txt` or `.csv` file via sql-commands. So the table-data is not kept in the database-tablespace but it is rather some kind of view on the sequential dataset. So there is no way the database can index or update the data since it is outside it's scope but it can only do selects on it.

Answer (score 4):

"External Table" means you have a (typically) CSV file stored on your file system and Oracle reads this CSV file defined by settings in CREATE TABLE statement. The data is not saved in Oracle Tablespace but you can select them like a normal table. However, you can only select them (or logically create a view from it) but you cannot modify anything.

Here a simple example of an external table:

```
CREATE TABLE ADHOC_CSV_EXT (
  C1   VARCHAR2(4000),
  C2   VARCHAR2(4000),
  C3   VARCHAR2(4000)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (  
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY SOME_FOLDER
   ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        records delimited BY newline 
        fields terminated BY ',' optionally enclosed BY '"' 
        missing field VALUES are NULL)
   LOCATION ('foo.csv')
);
```